# Add several rows header in an existing csv file

Tags: python, csv, header

I have a group of csv files, and I need to add to all of them a specific header compounded by 6 different rows:

`header = ['Plantillas.mot', 'version=1', 'nRows='+str(len(data1)), 'nColumns=7', 'inDegrees=yes', 'endheader']`

I am trying everything, my last try:

```
header = ['Plantillas.mot', 'version=1', 'nRows='+str(len(data1)), 'nColumns=7', 'inDegrees=yes', 'endheader']
import csv
ordered_filenames = header
with open('mycsv.csv') as csvfile, open(rute+'/loadsol/result1.mot',"w",newline='') as result:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=ordered_filenames)
    wtr = csv.DictWriter(result, ordered_filenames)
    wtr.writeheader()
    for line in rdr:
        wtr.writerow(line)
```

But that gives me all the header in the same row, and I need the header to appear like this:

```
Plantillas.mot
version=1
nRows=821
nColumns=7
inDegrees=yes
endheader
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a newline character to each header name and write that string:

```py
header = ['Plantillas.mot', 'version=1', 'nRows='+str(len(data1)), 'nColumns=7', 'inDegrees=yes', 'endheader']
header = '\n'.join(header)
```